# Using Dell omconfig with Vyatta

Tags: dell-poweredge, debian-squeeze, vyatta

We are running Vyatta Core 6.2, based on Debian Squeeze, on a Dell R710 server.

I came across these instructions to install the command line Dell Management utilities:
http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/deb/latest/

So I installed srvadmin-all, and it all seemed to work fine.
However, omconfig, omreport and other Dell tools are not available.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found these instructions:
http://www.openfusion.net/linux/dell_omsa

I had to run the last step after installation:

```
# Finally, you can update your path by doing logout/login, or just run:
. /etc/profile.d/srvadmin-path.sh
```